# ArgumentError: invalid date DateTime.now().change() for month with 2, 4, 6, 9, 11

Tags: ruby, datetime

I am changing month of the DateTime with some dynamic month.

I used `DateTime.now.change(month: month)`

It works only when month value is from  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]

when I tried with [2, 4, 6, 9, 11] it returns `ArgumentError: invalid date` error

```
irb(main):073:0> DateTime.now.change(month: 1)
=> Sat, 31 Jan 2015 19:59:28 +0530

irb(main):075:0> DateTime.now.change(month: 3)
=> Tue, 31 Mar 2015 19:59:33 +0530

irb(main):077:0> DateTime.now.change(month: 5)
=> Sun, 31 May 2015 19:59:39 +0530

irb(main):079:0> DateTime.now.change(month: 7)
=> Fri, 31 Jul 2015 19:59:44 +0530

irb(main):080:0> DateTime.now.change(month: 8)
=> Mon, 31 Aug 2015 19:59:48 +0530

irb(main):082:0> DateTime.now.change(month: 10)
=> Sat, 31 Oct 2015 19:59:54 +0530

irb(main):084:0> DateTime.now.change(month: 12)
=> Thu, 31 Dec 2015 20:00:00 +0530

irb(main):074:0> DateTime.now.change(month: 2)
irb(main):076:0> DateTime.now.change(month: 4)
irb(main):078:0> DateTime.now.change(month: 6)
irb(main):081:0> DateTime.now.change(month: 9)
irb(main):083:0> DateTime.now.change(month: 11)
ArgumentError: invalid date
    from /home/kiprosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb:35:in `civil'
    from /home/kiprosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb:35:in `change'
    from (irb):76
    from /home/kiprosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/kiprosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/kiprosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

why it is not working month value with [2, 4, 6, 9, 11]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `now()` is `2015-08-31`.  The months which don't work don't have 31 days.

Comment: oops... I didnt notice... Thanks @isowen

Comment: Had this issue with changing year. Took forever to remember February 29th. grrrrrr.